# Procedure to check the cost for product on Oracle

Tags: oracle, procedure

I have a question about procedure on Oracle and hope you guys and help me.I have these 3 table:

Ingredient:
**Ingredient_Number PK**
    Ingredient_Name,
    Quantity_On_Hand,
    Reorder_Point,
    Current_Cost,

Menu_Item
**Menu_Item_Number     PK**
    Menu_Item_Name,
    Current_Price,
    Production_Cost,

Menu_Item_Ingredient
    ***Menu_Item_Number     PK/FK,
    Ingredient_Number   PK/FK***,
    Quantity_Needed,

I tried to create the procedure to update the Production_Cost on Menu_Item table if Production_Cost < Quantity_Needed * Current_cost* 0.75 and I ended up with these code:

```
Create or Replace Procedure PR_Check_Cost
(P_Menu_Item_Number Number, P_Ingredient Number)
authid current_user 
IS
V_Productiton_Cost Number (6,2);
V_Current_Cost
V_Quantity_Needed Number (5,2);

CURSOR C_Cost 
IS
Select Production_Cost
INTO V_Production_Cost
From Menu_Item
Where Menu_Item_Number= P_Menu_Item_Number; 


Begin
Open C_Cost;

Select Quantity_Needed
Into V_Quantity_Needed
FROM Menu_Item_Ingredient
WHERE Ingredient_Number = P_Ingredient_Number
AND Menu_Item_Number = P_Menu_Item_Number;

Select Current_Cost
INTO V_CurrentCost
From Ingredient
Where Ingredient_Number = P_Ingredient_Number;

Fetch C_Product_Cost INTO V_Current_Cost, V_Quantity_Needed
While C_Product_Cost%FOUND LOOP


If (V_Quantity_Needed * V_Current_Cost * 0.75) > V_Production_Cost
{
    UPDATE Menu_Item
    SET Production_Cost = V_Quantity_Needed * V_Current_Cost * 0.75
    Where Menu_Item_Number = P_Menu_Item_Number
    AND Ingredient-Number = P_Ingredient_Number; 
}


End PR_Check_Cost;/
SHOW ERRORS;
```

Is there anyway to change my procedure to check and update the Production_Cost automatically whenever user update the Current_Cost and Quantity_Needed columns without enter the input data for **Menu_Item_Number(PK) and Ingredient_Number(PK)** columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that will only query what you need to update and then update them using bulk.  It will perform quite well as an added bonus.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE update_pr_costs
AS
DECLARE

    menu_item_tab IS TABLE OF ROWTYPE%MENU_ITEM
        INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

    menu_items menu_item_tab;

Begin

Select
    mi.Menu_Item_Number,
    mi.Menu_Item_Name,
    mi.Current_Price,
    (mii.Quantity_Needed * ig.Current_Cost * 0.75) Production_Cost
BULK COLLECT INTO menu_items
FROM Menu_Item_Ingredient mii
JOIN Ingredient ig
ON mii.Ingredient_Number = ig.Ingredient_Number
LEFT JOIN Menu_Item mi
ON mi.Ingredient_Number = ig.Ingredient_Number
AND mii.Menu_Item_Number = mi.Menu_Item_Number
WHERE (ig.Current_Cost * mii.Quantity_Needed * 0.75) > mi.Production_Cost;

FORALL i in menu_items.FIRST .. menu_items.LAST
    UPDATE Menu_Item
    SET Production_Cost = menu_items(i).Production_Cost
    where Menu_Item_Number = menu_items(i).Menu_Item_Number
    AND Ingredient_Number = menu_items(i).Ingredient_Number; 


End PR_Check_Cost;/
SHOW ERRORS;
```

Trigger that can be used to kick off the procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ingredient_after_update
AFTER UPDATE
   ON Ingredient
BEGIN
   update_pr_costs;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER menu_item_ing_after_update
AFTER UPDATE
   ON Menu_Item_Ingredient
BEGIN
   update_pr_costs;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but can I do that with only procedure and cursor??

Comment: Yes. Your other option would be to create two triggers with AFTER UPDATE. Those triggers would call this procedure with no inputs and only update the records which need to be. I will update my answer with an example.

Comment: I meant can I get it done with only procedure,cursor and joining table?

Comment: The procedure without a trigger does exactly that.  The SELECT INTO BULK COLLECT statement could be a cursor if you really wanted but it is unnecessary.  A cursor is simply a placeholder object that points to a current row.  If you can avoid updating row by row it always more efficient and less code to support.  In your case this seems to be the best way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Actually, 1 Menu_Item_Number can has 2 or 3 different ingredient_Number, so the formula should be:
(sum of all (Quantity_Needed * Current_cost)) * 0.75. 
I'm sorry about that :(

Comment: You will need to create a temporary table in your query for the menu_item_ingredient such as `select menu_item_number, sum(quantity_needed*cost) new_cost from menu_item_ingredient join ingredient on ingredient_number = ingredient_number)` and replace the `FROM Menu_Item_Ingredient mii
JOIN Ingredient ig
ON mii.Ingredient_Number = ig.Ingredient_Number` up above to just `FROM temp_table`